# Magento 2 admin ui component grid is not working

Tags: admin, grid, uicomponent, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5, I am creating custom admin grid using ui_component. But it is not working. Admin page showing but the grid part is keeps on loading.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/T5BJPKhj) is my `di.xml` code.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/xz70DipV) is my `ui component` code.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/V1mJ7Ha6) is my collection code.

[Reference link](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you forget to remove any die / vardump call on your controller ?

Comment: Please add your ResourceCollection and grid/collection code in question

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli, No, am not used any die/exit.

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, Updated in the question